# How to make check present token in localStorage during the routing stage?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I make registration in my app. When the user successfully passes the validation and submits the form to the server, `token` is stored in localStorage and redirects it to the `home` page. That is, if there is no token cannot be redirect to the `home` page.

I implement that like this in file Home.js:

```
const Home = () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("myToken")
    return (
        <div>
            {!token && <Redirect to="/" />}
            <Header/>
            <h1 >Home page</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

But the person who reviewed my app say:

> Not the best approach. Suppose we can have many such components - and we will each have such logic to write? And if it changes - then run everywhere to change?

This is it about the logic:
`{!token && <Redirect to="/" />}`
I wrote specifically in the Home.js file

And he suggested how it could be done differently:

> The best option would be to check the user's token during the routing stage. That is, split all routes in the application into unauthorized and authorized ones.

This is my file App.js where I have routing in my application:

```
const history = createBrowserHistory();

class App extends React.Component {
  render(){ 
    return (
      <BrowserRouter history={history}> 
         <div className="wrapper">
          <div className="content">

            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={SignupForm} /> 
              <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
              <Route path="/login" component={LoginForm} />
            </Switch>

           </div>
       </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
   )
  }
}
```

How to implement check the user's jwt-token during the routing stage(in file App.js where located my routes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can achieve this.. You can modify it according to your use case and put before `switch` begin.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Redirect, Route, Switch, BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("myToken");
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="wrapper">
          <div className="content">

              <Route exact path="/home" render={() => (
                  token ?
                      (<Redirect to="/home"/>) :
                      (<Redirect to="/login"/>)
              )}/>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" render={()=><div>MAin</div>} />
              <Route path="/home" render={()=><div>Home</div>} />
              <Route path="/login" render={()=><div>Login</div>} />
            </Switch>

          </div>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Let me know if u couldn't get this.

Comment: can you adapt your answer to my code? because i'm begginer and i tried to write like that and it didn't work...

Comment: do you just want that if user goes to `/home`, if  the token not found then redirect to login????

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I need. If no token in localStorage - the user cannot go to the page ```home```.

Comment: plz try, i have modified the code and let me know. Put it outside before switch.

Comment: when I write like this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-dream-sob6r?file=/App.js
In my monitor I have empty page.

Comment: First check the above code again, I've updated it. And put it above your `<switch>` component.

Comment: Just like you wrote I tried it too. But it doesn't work either, could you do a sandbox fork and write it right there? Maybe I misunderstood something

Comment: Check now added full code, just replace render with your `component`....

Comment: But I need not ```<div>MAin</div> ``` and etc. I need that render my component:SignupForm,Home,LoginForm. Because there are my forms and more... Also I want that also if no token start page was registration - not autorization. Path to my registration page is - ```/```. So I wrote that you say with my small changes:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-browser-b2se4?file=/App.js
But I have a new problem:
It does not redirect to the ```home``` page automatically. Only when I manually write the path in the browser line, then the redirect happens

Comment: I have this error:
```index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    in SignupForm (created by Context.Consumer) ```